# Promise result with then/catch

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I test ES6 Promise in react APP, but i've not result on my .then :

```
function addItem (value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    document.getElementById('todo').innerHTML += `<li>${value}</li>`;
  });
}

addItem(value).then(() => {
  alert('then !');
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

My function is executed, but i've not event on my then.

Do you know where i was wrong ? Thank you ! :)

Comment: Your `addItem` function isn't asynchronous, so you probably shouldn't be making it return a `Promise`. If you're doing it to be able to chain `then` calls afterwards, you can just start off with `Promise.resolve(addItem(value)).then(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call either reject or resolve in your promise.

```
function addItem (value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    document.getElementById('todo').innerHTML += `<li>${value}</li>`;
    resolve();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I've add this : `resolve(document.getElementById('todo').innerHTML += `<li>${value}</li>`);` It's correct or i need to add resolve() after ?

Answer (score 1):

Promises are used for asynchronous tasks. There's no point in using them to execute synchronous code. In you example, `then()` is not working because you never resolve the promise. In order to resolve it, you need to call `resolve()`.

Comment: Not quite true. You can use a promise for a synchronous task if you want to expose an asynchronous API. That way you can switch to an asynchronous implementation later.

Comment: @JakubHampl Yes, but that's a rare use-case, and in such situations it's better to simply return `Promise.resolve()` instead of wrapping the whole code in a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve your promise, for example:

```
function addItem (value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    document.getElementById('todo').innerHTML += `<li>${value}</li>`;
    resolve(10);
  });
}

addItem(value).then((data) => {
  alert('then !');
  console.log(data);// 10
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the `resolve` and `reject` function in your Promise.

`resolve` is a function that you call when you're done with your action.

```
resolve();
```

The argument that you pass to `resolve()` is what you get back in the `then` function.

`reject` is a function that you call when there's a error with your action. If you don't have anything to reject then you can just leave it out and you won't have to call it.

```
reject();
```

the argument that you pass to `reject()` is what you get back in the `catch` function.